# TypeError: App.cable is undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, actioncable

I have a problem with running ActionCable on my machine.

In assets/javascripts/channels I have two files:

index.coffee

```
#= require action_cable
#= require_self
#= require_tree .

@App = {}
App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer()
```

and question.coffee

```
App.question = App.cable.subscriptions.create "QuestionChannel",
  connected: ->
    # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
    # Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel

  follow: ->
    @perform 'follow'

  unfollow: ->
    @perform 'unfollow'
```

my application.js file looks like this:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require icheck
//= require homer/scripts
//= require Chart
//= require excanvas
//= require channels
//= require_tree .
```

When I start cable server and rails server and visit localhost:3000 in firefox console I see two errors:

```
SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified


this.webSocket = new WebSocket(this.consumer.url);
```

and

```
TypeError: App.cable is undefined


App.question = App.cable.subscriptions.create("QuestionChannel", {
```

I'm using rails 5 beta 3. How can I fix this?

Comment: So `ActionCable.createConsumer()` must be returning undefined.

Comment: When I type in firefox console ```ActionCable.createConsumer()``` it returns ```SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified this.webSocket = new WebSocket(this.consumer.url);```

Comment: So what is the value of `this.consumer.url`?

Answer (score 1):

`ActionCable.createConsumer` needs one parameter - address to Action Cable server.

```
@App = {}
App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer("ws://cable.example.com")
```

If You miss this parameter, then `this.customer.url` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have

```
<%= action_cable_meta_tag %>
```

somewhere in your applicaiton layout.

Rails by default generates and it takes care of providing the cable URL to Action Cable so that you don't have to pass it to

```
ActionCable.createConsumer()
```

.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I changed my server to puma whaaala it worked!

You can change by adding `gem 'puma'` and run `bundle`.

Also, make sure you `config.action_cable.url = "ws://localhost:3000/cable"` in your development.rb file. Good luck